# why i cant import my own clases on python 3.8x

Tags: python, importerror

I am new on python and i started course on udemy. I am watching classes summary right now and my issue is that i created a 3 classes listed below

```
gaston@gaston-ThinkPad-T470:\~/Documents/Python/bootcamp/clases/figuraGeometrica/Clases$ ls -lrt
total 16
\-rw-rw-r-- 1 gaston gaston  72 mar 22 17:59 color.py
  
\-rw-rw-r-- 1 gaston gaston 115 mar 23 09:34 figuraGeometrica.py
  
\-rw-rw-r-- 1 gaston gaston  77 mar 24 10:14 __init__.py
\-rw-rw-r-- 1 gaston gaston 305 mar 24 10:14 cuadrado.py
  
gaston@gaston-ThinkPad-T470:\~/Documents/Python/bootcamp/clases/figuraGeometrica/Clases$ py --version
Python 3.8.10
```

`cuadrado.py`:

```py
from .figuraGeometrica import figuraGeometrica  
from .color import color  
  
class cuadrado(figuraGeometrica,color):
  
    def __init__(self, lado, color):
figuraGeometrica.__init__(self, lado, lado)
  
        color.__init__(self,color)

        def calcularArea (self):   
            return self.ancho * self.alto
```

`color.py`:

```py
class color: 
    def init(self,color): 
        self.color = color
```

`figuraGeometrica.py`:

```py
class figuraGeometrica: 
    def init(self, ancho, alto): 
        self.ancho = ancho 
        self.alto = alto
```

When I tried to run `python cuadrado.py` I received below error...

```
gaston@gaston-ThinkPad-T470:\~/Documents/Python/bootcamp/clases/figuraGeometrica/Clases$ py cuadrado.py
**Traceback (most recent call last):**
File "cuadrado.py",   
line 1, in \<module\>
from .figuraGeometrica import figuraGeometrica
Import  
Error: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Any suggestion?

I tried below solutions but didnt work

https://itsmycode.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package/

Comment: init functions need to be written as `__init__(self, ...)`

Comment: Try to import without the period in front of the file name.

Comment: did it but i have same issue.

Comment: i was using vsc, i swapped to pychar, created a package with all files and worked...